# Multiple aws beanstalk worker tiers with the same code

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have multiple php worker tiers that are listening to different sqs queues, however, the code that is deployed to those workers is always identical. is there a way to make multiple workers use the same ec2 instance?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as using the same EC2 instances, this isn't possible.

I'd be interested in seeing your use case for having the same code but with different queues. Since this is the case, could you merge the queues into a single queue?

Comment: Hi, i could theoretically merge them into the same queue, however, the reason i'm not doing so is because each queue has a different priority. the code is the same but its because im using an API that includes anything those workers needs to do and activate the correct controller & method according to the message im getting from the queue. So even if a wrong task gets into the wrong queue, it should wrong perfectly fine, it will just be prioritized differently.